# Sitecore Analytics cookie id does not match in MongoDB Contacts table records

Tags: xdb, mongodb, interaction

I have `Sitecore 8.2` installed in my local environment. I was investigating that is analytics/xDB working correctly in my setup. I opened my site with a browser and saved the cookie `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` value for myself and the browser a few pages. I waited that the session ends so that Sitecore flushed the data to `MongoDB`. I checked the interactions table in MongoDb and I can find the record where I visited the pages. What I noticed also is that the id of ContactId in that record does not match the one that I took from the cookie in the browser, although the Pages that were visited are correct. I did this a few times to make sure. Also, the Contacts table didn't have the same value.

Looking at the Sitecore documentation I understood that the cookie `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` value should be the same as `ContactId`. How come in my case it isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse contact id from cookie value to `Guid` first and then convert it to `ToBase64String`.

Something like:

```
// Id of the Contact in the format xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
string contactId = "50638e2f-43b2-46ee-806d-665f4fb08954";
    
var guid = Guid.Parse(contactId);
var bytes = guid.ToByteArray();

string encodedId = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

You will receive `encodedId` in a form similar to `L45jULJD7kaAbWZfT7CJVA==`.

Then you can query MongoDB using:

```
db.getCollection('Contacts').find({_id:new BinData(3, 'L45jULJD7kaAbWZfT7CJVA==')})
```

**Code copied from and more details:** https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2017/04/30/how-to-find-sitecore-contacts-in-xdb-mongodb/

Comment: thank you, now I can find the records from MongoDB